# How do I get the 10 smallest numbers of an array?

Tags: python, arrays

This is my code:

```
from astropy.io import fits
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import heapq 

datos = fits.open('/home/citlali/Descargas/Lista.fits')
data = datos[1].data

#Linea [SIII] 9532
Mask_1 = data['flux_[SIII]9531.1_Re_fit'] / data['e_flux_[SIII]9531.1_Re_fit'] > 5
newdata1 = data[Mask_1]

H1_alpha = newdata1['log_NII_Ha_Re']

H1_beta = newdata1['log_OIII_Hb_Re']

M = H1_alpha < -0.9

newx = H1_alpha[M] #This is my array where I need the smallest 10 numbers
newy = H1_beta[M]  

sm = heapq.nsmallest(10, newx)

plt.plot(sm, newy, 'ro')
```

I want the 10 smallest numbers of newx but also I need "y" values (newy) of this numbers and idk how to get them.
Thanks.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Sorting the array? Getting a slice from it? Is the array so large that sorting is not an option?

Comment: @Grismar He needs the corresponding values from `newy`.

Comment: @Grismar I think the problem is that OP wants the *corresponding* values from `newy` as well - i.e. `newx` and `newy` were "parallel lists" to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, you're both right - misread on the first go, apologies

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be clear, does this code use Numpy? It looks as though  `M = H1_alpha < -0.9` is trying to mask a Numpy array. Please read [ask] and [mre] to make the question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is a basic Python data structure, you can use `zip` as user @barmar indicated.

```
import heapq

newx = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]
newy = [11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81]

sm = heapq.nsmallest(4, zip(newx, newy))
print(sm)
```

If you're using `pandas`, you can use the `.nsmallest()` method of the series and use the index of the result to get the matching results from the other series (saving you the creation of a 3rd data structure that has a copy of all the data again):

```
from pandas import Series

newx = Series(newx)
newy = Series(newy)

smx = newx.nsmallest(4)
smy = newy[smx.index]
print(smx, smy)
```

If you're just using `numpy`, this works:

```
import numpy as np

anewx = np.array(newx)
anewy = np.array(newy)

smxi = np.argpartition(anewx, 4)[:4]
print(anewx[smxi])
print(anewy[smxi])
```

Results of the combined code running:

```
[(10, 11), (20, 21), (30, 31), (40, 41)]
0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
dtype: int64 0    11
1    21
2    31
3    41
dtype: int64
[20 10 30 40]
[21 11 31 41]
```

Answer (score 1):

the documentation for heapq.nsmallest shows that you can give it a key:

> heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable, key=None)

this means that you can zip the newx and newy values together and then choose the nsmallest based on the newx values.

```
M = H1_alpha < -0.9

newx = H1_alpha[M]
newy = H1_beta[M]  

sm = heapq.nsmallest(10, zip(newx, newy), key= lambda x: x[0])

plt.plot([i[0] for i in sm], [i[1] for i in sm], 'ro')
```

Comment: It's not actually necessary to specify a custom key, because the natural comparison for tuples will compare values element-wise anyway.

Comment: yes you are right, I've specified that such a functionality exists for learning purposes

Answer (score 0):

Combine `newx` and `newy` into a list of tuples. Then you can get the 10 smallest from this, and split them back into separate lists to sort.

```
sm = heapq.nsmallest(10, zip(newx, newy)) # zip them to sort together
newx, newy = zip(*sm) # unzip them
plt.plot(newx, newy, 'ro')
```